# memory leak in my hashtable c++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, hashmap, hashtable

I created a hashtable class and wrote its destructor in this way

```
HashMap::~HashMap()
{
    for (int i=0; i<cap; i++)
    {
        Node* ptr = Hashtable[i];
        while (ptr)
        {
            Node* delptr;
            delptr=ptr;
            ptr=ptr->next;
            delete delptr;
        }
    }
    delete [] Hashtable;
}
```

Since it has a destructor, why it is keeps leak memory?

Here is how I implement a constructor

```
HashMap::HashMap()
{
    Hashtable= new Node* [INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT];
    sz=0;
    cap=INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT;
    hashfunction=defaulthashfunction;
}
```

The additem function is :

```
void HashMap::add(const std::string& key, const std::string& value)
{
    int index = hashfunction(key)%cap;;
    Node* ptr=Hashtable[index];
    Node* newnode=new Node;
    if (contains(key)==false)
    {
        if (ptr == nullptr)
        {
            newnode->key=key;
            newnode->value=value;
            newnode->next=NULL;
            Hashtable[index]=newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            newnode->key=key;
            newnode->value=value;
            newnode->next=NULL;
            while(ptr->next != NULL)
            {
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next=newnode;
         }}
    if (loadFactor() > 0.8)
    {
        int newcap = cap*2+1;
        Node** newhash = new Node* [newcap];
        rehash(newhash, Hashtable, cap, newcap);
        for (int i=0; i <cap; i++)
        {
            Node* ptr=Hashtable[i];
            while (ptr)
            {
                Node* delptr;
                delptr=ptr;
                ptr=ptr->next;
                delete delptr;
            }
        }
        delete [] Hashtable;
        Hashtable=newhash;
    }
}
```

Here is my rehash function, the only error is always this line: Node* nnode = new Node;
if I put this code out side of the loop, the error becomes 20, and it indicates the problem is in my destructor. But before resize my hashtable, it does not have error and I test several times. Why is the rehash function keeps leak memory?

```
void HashMap::rehash(Node** newhash, Node** oldhash, int oldcap, int newcap)
{
    for (int x=0; x<newcap; x++)
    {
        newhash[x]=NULL;
    }
    //Node* nnode = new Node;
    for (int i = 0; i<oldcap; i++)
    {
        Node* ptr=oldhash[i];
        while (ptr!=NULL)
        {

            int index = hashfunction(ptr->key)%newcap;
            Node* nptr=newhash[index];
            Node* nnode = new Node;
            if (nptr==NULL)
            {
                nnode->key=ptr->key;
                nnode->value=ptr->value;
                nnode->next=NULL;
                newhash[index]=nnode;
            }
            else
            {
                while (nptr->next != NULL)
                {
                    nptr=nptr->next;
                }
                nnode->key=ptr->key;
                nnode->value=ptr->value;
                nnode->next=NULL;
                nptr->next=nnode;
                }
            ptr=ptr->next;
         }
    }
}
```

-- INSERT --

Comment: And you're **sure** `HashMap::~HashMap()` is actually being called? On a related not, stop using uninitialized data evals. In case you don't know what those are `int a; if (a < 10)...` is an example. Another: `int *p; if (p != nullptr)...` Doing such invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Without being being able to see your declarations it won't be possible to tell if you're cleaning up appropriately.

Comment: How can I initialize a data?    Do I need to call ~HashMap()??? Otherwise, why is not being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in the Valgrind output suggests a memory leak.

```
==6949== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6949==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6949==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

However, Valgrind *is* telling you that you didn't initialize some data:

```
==6949== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6949==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==6949==    at 0x402B774: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==6949==    by 0x804A75C: HashMap::HashMap() (HashMap.cpp:31)

==6949== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6949==    at 0x402B774: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==6949==    by 0x804A75C: HashMap::HashMap() (HashMap.cpp:31)

==6949== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
```

Specifically, your constructor, `HashMap::HashMap() (HashMap.cpp:31)`, the problem is there, not your destructor.

Finally, your code crashes because of a null-pointer access.

```
==6949== Invalid read of size 4
==6949==    at 0x40EAD76: std::string::assign(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18)
==6949==    by 0x804A51A: main (main.cpp:16)
==6949==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

You should look at main.cpp's line 16 and see what it is doing, but until you fix those uninitialized values all bets are off.

Comment: Yes! How can I initialize values??                                ==6949==    at 0x804B004: HashMap::size() const (HashMap.cpp:274)
==6949==    by 0x804AF87: HashMap::loadFactor() const (HashMap.cpp:293)    Those are all functions that takes no parameter and returns a value.

Comment: The problem is your **constructor**. Valgrind is saying `Uninitialised value was created ... HashMap::HashMap()`. According to ValGrind that's at `HashMap.cpp` line `31`.

Comment: It means one or more of your member variables is not being initialized. Either of your `HashMap` or `Node` classes.

Comment: For instance - you're not setting any of your `m_hashTable[]` values to NULL or adding `()` after the `[INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT]`.

Comment: you mean I initialize a Hashtable, but it is an empty array of bucket?

Comment: So I just need to make a pointer for each bucket and let the pointer points to null.

Comment: I have one more question, if my Hashtable enlarge its size and I rehash the element again, do I need to initialize everything again first?

Comment: ==8628== ERROR SUMMARY: 14 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Comment: I did what you tell me and then I got no errors and no memory leaks, but now it comes again! I don't know why! I edited and added the detail of error at the end of my code example.

Comment: If you change the allocation to be: `HashTable = new Node* [INITIAL_BUCKET_COUNT]()` (note '()' at the end) it will default-initialize the values to zero. Otherwise, you will need to go thru all the buckets and assign them an initial value of `nullptr` (or NULL if you don't have C++11).

ValGrind has an option, `--db-attach=yes` which will have it attach a debugger when it encounters an error, that way you can see what is going on. But you may also want to run your app under gdb with the `-tui` argument and walk thru what is happening.

Comment: Yes, I initialize them all to NULL now, and the error reduced to 2. I updated my error message, it still shows "Invalid read of size 4" What does that mean?

Comment: Only looks like one. Main.cpp. line 7 you're passing a null ptr to a std::string or trying to dereference a null ptr to a string. You'll have to catch that in the debugger or post the function that is in along with line numbers as comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved this problem! ....But now I have a problem when I resize the hashtalbe, please help T T I edited the above entry.

Comment: At this point, you would be best to mark this as an answer to the original question and post a second question with the focus on your rehash function.

Comment: I would also strongly encourage you to make all of your member variables distinct, many people use a "m_" prefix of member-variable names, "g_" for globals, "s_" for statics. E.g instead of `HashTable` (which looks like a type, the syntax highlighting here actually colors it blue) `m_hashTable`. Etc.

Comment: Here's a quick stab at writing a rehash function for a hash table like yours: http://pastebin.com/pq5j2i4q

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037721/how-to-write-a-correct-hash-table-destructor-in-c  I write a new entry...

Comment: This link helps a lot! But I find the error essentially is the line which I use "new" to create a Node. But I have to use it, and the destructor does not deallocate it. I can't just use "delete xx" because this also gives me error.

Comment: It's actually telling you that you are sometimes allocating it and NOT deleting it.

Comment: Please move extended discussion to [chat], thanks :)