# How to write a correct Hash Table destructor in c++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, hashmap, hashtable, destructor

I am writing a c++ Hashtable

Here is my destructor:

```
HashMap::~HashMap()
{
    for (int i=0; i<cap; i++)
    {
        Node* ptr = Hashtable[i];
        while (ptr!=NULL)
        {
            Node* delptr;
            delptr=ptr;
            ptr=ptr->next;
            delete delptr;
        }
    }
    delete [] Hashtable;
}
```

My add function:

```
void HashMap::add(const std::string& key, const std::string& value)
{
    int index = hashfunction(key)%cap;;

    Node* ptr=Hashtable[index];
    Node* newnode=new Node;

    if (contains(key)==false)
    {
        if (ptr == nullptr)
        {

            newnode->key=key;
            newnode->value=value;
            newnode->next=NULL;
            Hashtable[index]=newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            newnode->key=key;
            newnode->value=value;
            newnode->next=NULL;

            while(ptr->next != NULL)
            {
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next=newnode;
         }}}
```

But I keeps getting memory leak error

```
==13676== 
==13676== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13676==     in use at exit: 12 bytes in 1 blocks
==13676==   total heap usage: 42 allocs, 41 frees, 669 bytes allocated
==13676== 
==13676== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==13676==    at 0x402BE94: operator new(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==13676==    by 0x804BF8D: HashMap::add(std::string const&, std::string const&) (HashMap.cpp:112)
==13676==    by 0x804AFD2: main (main.cpp:18)
==13676== 
==13676== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13676==    definitely lost: 12 bytes in 1 blocks
==13676==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13676==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13676==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13676==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13676== 
==13676== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13676== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The line its indicates is Node* newnode=new Node; because I use "new" here, this newnode needed to be deallocated, but the destructor only deallocate content in Hashtable. If I don't use "newnode", I will have null-pointer access error because nullptr does not have access to Node (Node is a struct has key and value), I can only let the pointer points to a "newnode."However, adding extra "delete newnode" makes me getting more than 20 errors. I really need you help!

If I write this, I still get an error

```
if (contains(key)==false)
{
    if (ptr == nullptr)
    {
        Node* newnode=new Node;
        newnode->key=key;
        newnode->value=value;
        newnode->next=NULL;
        Hashtable[index]=newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* newnode=new Node;
        newnode->key=key;
        newnode->value=value;
        newnode->next=NULL;

        while(ptr->next != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next=newnode;
     }}
```

Comment: Does Node have a destructor too?

Comment: Don't allocate the node unless you already know the exact key isn't present in the collision chain. And don't call `contains(key)`. You already have the proper collision chain. Just walk it, and if the exact key isn't found, add it, else swap in the new value to the existing node.

Comment: @user3000888 Can you please edit your question and put a comment on the line that is `HashMap.cpp:112`?

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
Node* newnode=new Node;
```

creates a local newnode pointer which will go out of scope after the add function exits. This will leak memory allocated by new.

Comment: I know, but I need this line, how to dealloacate it? Simply write delete newnode gives more 380errors!

Comment: No, he's wrong. You store the newnode value either in HashTable[index] or in the ptr->next of the last node in the chain.

Comment: Actually, he's right - my bad. As WhozCraig said, you're calling "new" before you decide you NEED to add the entry.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing this:

```
Node* newnode=new Node;
if (contains(key)==false)
    // ... store it
/*
else
    leak it
*/
```

What you need to do is do the conditional BEFORE the new.

```
if(contains(key) == true) {
     // use the existing entry.
     ...
     return;
}
else {
    Node* newnode=new Node;
    // ... rest of your code for inserting a new entry here.
}
```

---- Edit ----

What ValGrind is telling you is that your code allocated a pointer at HashMap.cpp line 112, but it never stored the address -- this is what happens in your code when someone calls the add function with a key for which "contains(key)" does not return false. You don't store the pointer, and so the Node you allocated is left allocated but your code is not tracking it -> it's a leak.

Comment: I changed to allocate the pointer whenever I use it, but why I still get an error?

Comment: Because I also need "newnode" after if (contains(key)==false)

Comment: Still the error about Node* newnode=new Node; change its position several times, it does not work :(

Comment: When you use "new", the program allocates some memory and gives you the pointer. *You* are now the owner of that piece of memory. *You* are responsible for returning it to the system. ValGrind is telling you that one of the "Node" objects you allocated didn't get returned. You'll need to either post the entire code or you'll need to step through a simple test program in the debugger and watch for any instances where you might be leaking, e.g. in your remove node, rehash code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare the newnode and then after the if statement allocate the new Node. The way your code is right now the newnode can be allocated , the if statement goes wrong and the newnode stays in memory never used.